# Clojure - How to return a sequence?

Tags: clojure

`p-seq`: Receives two integer arguments, “from” and “to”, and this method should return a sequence containing only the numbers given by `is-p` function between “from” and “to”. The current code that I have written only prints out all the numbers between "from" and "to". I want p-seq to return a sequence.

`is-p`: checks and returns true if a number is a prime number otherwise returns false.

```
(defn p-seq [from to]
  (loop [count from]
    (if (> count to)
      (println "")
      (do
        (def seqf (is-p count))
          (if(= seqf true)
            (print count " ")
            )
  (recur (inc count))))))
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You simply can use `filter` function on sequence**, filter is applied on each element

given `is-p` function that checks prime number,

```
user=> (filter is-p (range 1 20))
(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19)
```

So, your `p-seq` function looks like,

```
user=> (defn p-seq [from to]
          (filter is-p (range from to)))
#'user/p-seq

user=> (p-seq 100 200)
(101 103 107 109 113 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173 179 181 191 193 197 199)
```

### references

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter

Comment: Perfect. Note the other answer too about `(range x y)` is actually `[x y-1]`, if you want y to be included do something like `(range from (+ 1 to))`, https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range describes it as well

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a *predicate* function `is-prime?` you could simply use it to filter the *range* of all numbers between `from` and `to`:

```
(filter is-prime? (range 100 200))
=> (101 103 107 109 113 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173 179 181 191 193 197 199)
```

Note the upper bound argument to `range` is exclusive.